# Run time and Big Theta Analysis

Tags: algorithm, big-o

So, I am going over Big Theta Analysis and run time analysis.

I have the code snippet

```
sum = 0
for i in range(0,n)
     for j in range (0,i**2)
         if j % 2 == 0:
              for k in range(0,j):
                   sum += 1
```

I am claiming that this has a run time of n^3*log(n^2). The reason for this is the first line gives us n and inside that the second loop would give us n^2 so we have n^3, but where I am unsure is the log(n^2). I know that we are looking for evens which will give us about half the values so maybe it would be n^2/2, but am a bit unsure.

The second part is finding a g(n) such that f(n) is Theta(g(n)). So if i have a run time of n^3 I know that g(n) would be n^3 as well since it is both in O(g(n) and Omega(g(n)). I just want to make sure I understand that correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct that the log(n^2) part is actually n^2/2.  You typically see log(n) in cases like binary search where you're dividing the size of the input on each iteration.

Comment: So, then I would get a f(n) = n^5 ?

Comment: @jam yup, you'd get n^5